# Enclosing the Raspberry Pi in a Plushie

Tags: temperature, case, cooling

As I've seen previous projects with the Raspberry Pi being enclosed in stuffed animals and plushies. I've wanted to attempt a project in a similar environment. Will there be a problem with overheating the device when it's enclosed in such a tight location? My Raspberry Pi is already in a Geaux Robot case, so there's that to be considered.

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/103/40

Comment: And here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105/40. Short answer; there are no ventilation or cooling requirements.

Comment: Therefore it's safe. The outside environment would be 100% room temperature for me, so It probably won't have a chance to overheat; I'll assume that placing metal eyelets for wire holes would count as more than sufficient ventilation. Thanks for the information. @goldilocks thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RPi is unlikely to be a problem. However if you insulate it well enough it will of course overheat eventually.

There will be a temperature gradient from the RPi to the out of the outside of you r Plushie.

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar question to:
[Environmental Tolerance](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/environmental-tolerance)
which has an answer regarding the temperature tolerance.